# Document data is removed with updated release via testflight after changing developer and creating new certificates and provisioning profiles

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, testflight

I have taken over from my developer to make a few minor updates to my universal IOS app (e.g. button rename etc).

I made the minor updates to the codebase the developer sent me, created a new dev and production certificate and provisioning profile for the app ID so I could test my changes on testflight before releasing. I released the build on testflight and everything works well except the **documents data is removed** from the build I had downloaded via the app store. The app data keeps some customised data the user has created and also some default images and data for the user to use.

This problem hasn't happened before on previous builds from the developer and he ensures me that he has sent the most recent code. I released his unchanged code via testflight from my laptop and it removed the documents data as per above. I have tried a number of things to see if my updated build doesn't remove the document data on my device but with no luck.

Things tried:

- Ensured my Bundle Identifier is exactly the same as the previous builds
- Removed all my certificates and provisioning profiles and started afresh with new certificates and provisioning profiles
- Updated my xcode to 5.0 (5A1413)
- When I created the IPA I used a the dev provisioning profile and then also tried a ad hoc distribution provisioning profile
- Cleared my phone of any old provisioning profiles before installing
- Copied the IPA directly to my device via xcode
- Played around with the code signing identity
- Changed the version and build numbers

I have read many other similar problems and tried the solutions but nothing has worked so far. Obviously I don't want to release on the app store before I know the problem isn't going to happen via the app store.

My initial thought was that its has to do with the provisioning profiles I have used as it was previously done via the other developers machine. I have asked for his certificate and provisioning profile to check but he doesn't believe that is the issue.

Any help would be much appreciated as I have spent many many hours (and many builds&releases) trying to get this to work.

Many thanks in advance.